# regular expression ending

Tags: python, regex

I have ONE string as plain text and want to *extract* phone numbers of any format from it.
Here is my  regex:

```
r = re.compile(r"(\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)[-\s*]\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{4})")
```

It extracts the following matches correctly:

```
617.933.6444
(880)-567-4565
(880) 567-4565
222-333-8888
555 666 4444
9999999999
```

But how can I avoid getting `7986815059` when I have `798681505951` in the text?

How to make an ending for my regex? (it should not contain letters and digits after and before, exact number count must be 10)

!!!!
Decision

If somebody needs to find US phone numbers in string, use link from the last Wiktor Stribiżew  comment.

Comment: Add `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Comment: I have ONE hole string as plain text. Adding `^`  at the start and `$` at the end wont help

Comment: I really don't understand how you made an input. https://regex101.com/r/QzRJIK/3

Comment: Well, do you mean you have an input like [here](https://regex101.com/r/QzrMa4/1)? And you want to extract those substrings?

Comment: Now it seems correctly. My bad, I didn't take in mind that I can place first \b inside the scope. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries, but placing them into your pattern is not obvious. It is due to the fact that the second alternative starts with a non-word char, `\(`. Thus, the first `\b` must be added at the beginning of the first alternative, and the trailing one at the very end of the pattern:

```
r'(\b\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)[-\s*]\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4})\b'
   ^^                                                               ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QzrMa4/2)

You may also require a non-word char or start of string before `(`. Then add `\B` at the second alternative start:

```
r'(\b\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}|\B\(\d{3}\)[-\s*]\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4})\b'
                                   ^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/QzrMa4/3)

Also, note that there is no need escaping a `.` inside a character class, it is already parsed as a literal dot in `[.]`. And no need using a lazy `??` quantifier, it does not make sense here and  a greedy version, `?`, will work equally well and will look "cleaner".